# How to change color of SVG icon in only one instance

Tags: css

I am trying to style my website at [mathbymiles.com](https://mathbymiles.com) and I am trying to color some social media link SVG icons in the footer of the website. I used the following code to change the colors to orange:

```
svg.fa.d-icon.d-icon-fab-facebook.svg-icon.svg-string, svg.fa.d-icon.d-icon-fab-twitter.svg-icon.svg-string, svg.fa.d-icon.d-icon-fab-patreon.svg-icon.svg-string, svg.fa.d-icon.d-icon-fab-quora.svg-icon.svg-string {
    color: #FF6C00;
}
```

So this gave me this desired result:

[image]

HOWEVER, other instances of these svg icons are now orange, too like here, which is undesired:
[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why are people trying to close this question? I would like to know what I did wrong for future reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Probably your question does not directly point to a problem. In fact, you need to guess the problem you are experiencing in order to find the problem. People may therefore see it as a question of poor quality.

If we come to the answer to the question,

```
svg.fa.d-icon.d-icon-fab-facebook.svg-icon.svg-string, svg.fa.d-icon.d-icon-fab-twitter.svg-icon.svg-string, svg.fa.d-icon.d-icon-fab-patreon.svg-icon.svg-string, svg.fa.d-icon.d-icon-fab-quora.svg-icon.svg-string {
    color: #FF6C00;
}
```

The CSS code you wrote above includes features that predominate by nature to include other icons. See [Class Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors).

Let's rewrite this to affect only the **icons** below,

```css
.social a.social-link svg.svg-icon
{
   color: #FF6C00 !important;
}
```

Thus, when there is a suitable match, we force it to be orange with "`! Important`". But if there is no match, we leave it to their natural state. Feel free to write if you have any problems.

**Note: Delete the one you added and replace it with the new one above.**

Comment: Thank you so much! This teaches me a lot and helps me understand CSS a lot more.